# ruby on rails 3, render multiple views in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem and I dont know how to solve it.
I have a user that log in a web site, and I identify them by session[:user_id] and user has a status page that is defined in user_controller and in status view.
So, I would like to make one page for admin, to see all the statuses from all users on one page, using already written controller and view.
Is that possible?
I could rewrite some of the code, so that I could call with params, like ?user_id=70 and then set session[:user_id]=params[:user_id], but it would be painful if I will have to rewrite whole statuses, beside i would have to maintain same code on 2 different places.
Thank you.
Dorijan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more functionality in your controller, you can add more actions to it. You can also do that in a resourcefull way. 
On the other hand it usually is best practice to keep controllers thin.

See: [ActionController](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

In order to make your views reusable, you should use partials. 
You could make a _user_status partial.html.erb and render a single partial for a user render all of them for an admin.

Checkout: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: ok, I just did that, but I also need logic and variables from original controller. How can I reuse them?

Comment: To share code between multiple controllers, you could put it in the ApplicationController. You could also consider to make your controllers inherit from each other. Maybe you should be more clear about what you have and what you are trying to do. It is kind of hard to tell from your short description...

Comment: I know it is hard for you to understand my problem :( ... but can I have for example in my controller User.all.each loop and within render 'status'...last time I tried I got error....

Comment: Ok...I think I found the solution in render_to_string